# Line height for inline element without changing the property to inline block

Tags: html, css

Please check the fiddler link which explains my problem better 
http://jsfiddle.net/vivekanandaJE/hx2wpggv/2/

```
h2{
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  display:inline;/* inline block spoils the  gap between lines*/
  line-height:30px;
}
```

All the solution i have come across changes the property as inline-block oneway or another. that doesn't solve my problem.

**To resume:**

I want to reduce the background color height and I cannot put inline block as **I need the gap** with no background between each line. I would like to adjust black background gap on right and left end too that's supported in all browsers.

Comment: mention the problem here than in a link.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get rid of the gaps that occur between the H2 element and other elements on your page then all you need really need to do is remove the margins and padding on the h2 element and make the line-height the same as the font-height. (see below)

```
h2{
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:32px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```

This will allow the H2 and any preceding or following elements to "touch" each other with no additional space in between.

If however you are talking about "space" which appears when when a single H2 line wraps inside its container element then this is a visual effect caused by the metric of the font you are using. The only way to deal with these currently is to use browser specific extensions for fonts (do a Google search for font feature settings) and take a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature for whether you can use them on your particular target browsers.

You would have to adjust combinations of the font settings made by the designers of that font and even then you can only do so much. If the font leaves space above and below each letter to allow for descenders and such then you are not going to be able to alter it significantly. Of course, you could always design your own font that touch top and bottom for each letter and there are tools out there to help you do that.

Comment: I want that gap between the lines of H2 element and to reduce the line height. that's the biggest headache here

Comment: To Reduce the gap between H2's just remove the padding and margin. as suggested. "Gap" around the font cannot be removed without using features not fully supported or choosing another font or building your own.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the h2 element in a div.
Use the below css:

```css
h2{
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    display:inline;
    font-size:1rem;
}

div{ line-height:30px; }
```

control the height of a line using font-size of h2, and gap between lines using line-height or the div.

Comment: my issue is not the gap between lines. i need to reduce the black gap(sort of font padding) occuring below and above the text